# iPhone 5s, lost Saturday, asking a question about stolen phones that I don't think anyone is asking

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Details
had it at restaurant lunch, may have had it at my only stop on way home (ice cream counter), after being home 30 minutes looked in car & didn't see it.

Called it, straight to voicemail.  It was on when I had it one hour earlier but not sure on battery left.

Find my Pphone said offline, but I do turn that on & off as needed & can't remember if it was on or off.

Sent lost phone message with phone number to call, set up email to me if it's connected, still within 90 minutes of last having it for sure.

More than 4 full days later, nothing.

**The question:**

I think someone got it, disconnected it immediately & has since probably switched it to a new number. Find still says it's offline, is there a way to see if that exact phone now is active on another number?

Comment: Changing the SIM card is how the number is changed, and findmyiphone doesn't care if that is done.  Findmyiphone will still work if the number/SIM card has been changed.  However if findmyiphone was turned off and the phone has been wiped you will not see it again because the appleid has been cleared. Leaving findmyiphone turned on prevents clearing the appleid from the phone until the correct password is supplied.

Comment: To add to Tyson's comment, don't switch off Find my iPhone or remote erase, as that would also 'give' them the phone.